# Difference between build time instrumentation and load time instrumentation

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation

Nowadays  I have been studying simple bytecode instrumentation mechanism for the sake of my knowledge and hope to use them in future projects in my company.

I have gone through several article available on line.Yet I'm confused about the term build time and load time.

I'm very grateful if someone clarify the meaning of these terms

Thanks,

Nuwan Arambage

Answer (score 5):

build time occurs when the code is built into a class or a jar from source.

load time occurs when the JVM loads the class. i.e. when the program runs.

build time instrumentation is often simpler to implement, but harder to use.